# curl post with _token still get "Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException" on laravel

Tags: php, curl, post, laravel-5, token

I am using two PHP frameworks now, one is laravel-5, the other is self-developed.
In one .php file of my own framework, I need to call an api on laravel. So I use cURL to send a post request.

Calling code:

```
$postfields = array(
            '_token' => $this->request['token'], // this is received from the view in laravel
            'product_ids' => $this->request['productIds']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I paid attention to use '_token' specifically. But I still got an exception in log. Like following:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/view/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/illuminate/pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /a/www/zhihui-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /a/www/zhihui-manager/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}
```

So I changed "post" request to "get" and used

```
header("Location:" . $url . http_build_query($postfields));
```

Then everything goes well.

But I'm afraid query field will expand in the future, so I prefer to use "post" and use CSRF to guarantee security.

What's the reason of the exception? Thanks in advance.

Updating:
As @Thành Chung Bùi said, I've added cookie using cURL in calling code:

```
$cookie = 'XSRF-TOKEN=' . $this->request['token'] . '; laravel_session=' . $this->request['session'];
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
```

These two values are gotten from code in laravel and are not empty exactly:

```
Cookie::get('laravel_session');
Cookie::get('XSRF-TOKEN');
```

But it didn't work for the same reason.

Comment: I'm curious to know how the view is currently passing token in `$this->request`. When you `dd($this->request['token'])` do you get a value?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I use Ajax in .js to pass some parameters to it. Definitely token can be printed out.

Comment: So laravel checks if the session token (commonly in cookies) matches that in the request. They both don't match as it is.

Comment: You must send request with cookie for laravel to verify token. The second works because its a redirect, that leads browser send with cookie

Comment: @ThànhChungBùi Since only token in cookie can be verified, why do we need to add {{csrf_field()}} in form which is sent to laravel? How does it take effect?

Comment: Base on the cookie you (or browser) sent to server, laravel will retrieve the saved token stored in session and compare it with the one you attach to payload(or csrf token header). Because you send request via curl, you must manually set cookie

Comment: @Thành Chung Bùi I've modified my code as you said, but it doesn't seems to work properly. Did something go wrong in my code?